# Updating values of three dot ellipsis in R

Tags: r, parameter-passing, ellipsis, rlang

I have a function `foo()` that I'd like to be able to call in two different "modes": once or within a while loop.

I thought using a somewhat generic wrapper (`runtime_gateway()`) and passing arguments via `...` to `foo()` would make sense here so I could leverage the same "runtime gateway logic" for arbitrary functions with different sets of arguments.

If run `foo()` within a while loop, I'd like to **update some** of its arguments while **keeping** the default or passed values of other arguments.

How would I do that?

I'm aware of `rlang::dot_list(...)` and friends and had a quick glance at https://github.com/r-lib/ellipsis. It seems that any of those would only let pluck values from or inspect ellipsis content, but I don't see how I could "update it in transit".

## Reprex

```
foo <- function(
  id = "id_a",
  at = Sys.time()
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("{id}: {at}"))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

runtime_gateway <- function(
  fun = foo,
  run_mode = c("once", "while"),
  ... # Args to be passed to `fun`
) {
  run_mode <- match.arg(run_mode)

  if (run_mode == "once") {
    fun(...)
  } else if (run_mode == "while") {
    counter <- 0

    while(counter < 3) {
      # Goal: keep ellipsis value for `id` but *update* value for `at`
      dots <- rlang::dots_list(...)
      at <- if ("at" %in% names(dots)) {
        message("`at` was passed via ellipsis:")
        message(dots$at)
        dots$at
      } else {
        Sys.time()
      }

      fun(at = at + 60, ...)
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
}

runtime_gateway()
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:09:16.779
runtime_gateway(at = lubridate::ymd_hms("2020-02-21 10:30:00"))
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 10:30:00

runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while")
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:10:18.897
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:10:19.900
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:10:20.902
runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while", id = "id_b")
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:10:21.905
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:10:22.906
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:10:23.908
runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while", at = lubridate::ymd_hms("2020-02-21 10:30:00"))
#> `at` was passed via ellipsis:
#> 2020-02-21 10:30:00
#> Error in fun(at = at + 60, ...): formal argument "at" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.3.0)

Comment: in the very last line, why are you attempting to pass an `at` argument at all, when it will already default to `Sys.time()`?

Comment: I mean, you are giving it a fixed time by passing `at = Sys.time()`. Why not just change `fun(at = Sys.time(), ...)` in your while loop to `fun(...)` and not pass an `at` argument at all?

Comment: @AllanCameron `at` and `Sys.time()` are just examples for arguments whose value needs to change if the function is run in a `while` loop

Comment: @AllanCameron: I've updated my question to hopefully make the part of updating `at` within `while` clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ensure that `dots` contains an `at` argument by adding it if it isn't present, then dispatch `fun` using `dots` instead of `...` with `do.call`

```r
runtime_gateway <- function(
  fun = foo,
  run_mode = c("once", "while"),
  ... # Args to be passed to `fun`
) {
  run_mode <- match.arg(run_mode)

  if (run_mode == "once") {
    fun(...)
  } else if (run_mode == "while") {
    counter <- 0

    while(counter < 3) {
      # Goal: keep ellipsis value for `id` but *update* value for `at`
      dots <- rlang::dots_list(...)
      if ("at" %in% names(dots)) {
        message("`at` was passed via ellipsis:")
        message(dots$at)
        dots$at <- dots$at + 60
      } else {
        dots$at <- Sys.time() + 60
      }

      do.call(fun, dots)
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
runtime_gateway()
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:22:07

runtime_gateway(at = lubridate::ymd_hms("2020-02-21 10:30:00"))
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 10:30:00

runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while")
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:23:09
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:23:10
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 14:23:11

runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while", id = "id_b")
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:23:12
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:23:13
#> id_b: 2020-02-21 14:23:14

runtime_gateway(run_mode = "while", at = lubridate::ymd_hms("2020-02-21 10:30:00"))
#> `at` was passed via ellipsis:
#> 2020-02-21 10:30:00
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 10:31:00
#> `at` was passed via ellipsis:
#> 2020-02-21 10:30:00
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 10:31:00
#> `at` was passed via ellipsis:
#> 2020-02-21 10:30:00
#> id_a: 2020-02-21 10:31:00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Slightly more idiomatic: `rlang::exec(fun, !!!dots)` instead of `do.call(...)` . Also, `rlang::list2()` has a simpler API than `rlang::dots_list()` .

Comment: Sorry, took me a couple of days to get back to this. Thanks for your answer and thanks @krlmlr for putting it on `rlang` rails. However, by switching to `do.call()` or `rlang::exec()` I essentially lose the "ease of use" of passing `...` even further downstream, right? Isn't there any way to somehow change this "syntactically sugared glorified arg list" that `...` essentially is while **keeping** the syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Rappster: The function that is called with `do.call()` still has the ellipsis in its signature. I'm not aware of a documented way to update part of `...` .